# Python fill login form

Tags: python

I'm new with python and I'm trying to login to webpage for getting some data from it

this is my code:

```
import requests 
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
url = "https://mano.eso.lt" 
driver.get(url) 
user = "xxxx@xxxx.com" 
password = "yyyyyyy"

payload = {
    "name[name]": user,
    "user[pass]": password
    }

s = requests.Session() 
p = s.post(url, data = payload) 
s.close 
driver.close
```

So all what I'm getting just opening webpage, but not filling forms and not sending info to webpage
Could anybody help with this code?

Thank you

Comment: You're mixing and matching Selenium/webdriver and requests. The two are entirely separate things and don't interact.

Answer (score 0):

I think the URL which you're trying to hit the POST request on is incorrect. You'll have to hit the same request on the API endpoint URL and not in the webpage URL.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I get some information:

```
    <form class="user-login-form" data-drupal-selector="user-login-form" novalidate="novalidate" autocomplete="off" action="/" method="post" id="user-login-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<div class="input-type type-email">
    <input autocorrect="none" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" autofocus="autofocus" data-drupal-selector="edit-name" aria-describedby="edit-name--description" type="email" id="edit-name" name="name" value="" size="60" maxlength="254" class="form-email required" required="required" aria-required="true" />
          </div>
          <div id="edit-name--description" class="description">
          Įveskite el.pašto adresą
        </div>

<div class="input-password-wrapper">
  <input autocomplete="off" data-drupal-selector="edit-pass" aria-describedby="edit-pass--description" type="password" id="edit-pass" name="pass" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text required" required="required" aria-required="true" />
  <span class="password-view-toggle"><i class="icon-eye-closed"></i></span>
</div>

      </div>
```

so I wrote a code like:

```
import time
from webbot import Browser
web = Browser()
web.go_to('https://mano.eso.lt')
time.sleep(5)
web.type('XXXXXX@xxxx.xxx', into = 'email')
time.sleep(1)
web.type('YYYYYYYYY', into = 'password')
```

result is that page is opening and email is writing to it. But for password it doesn't work. Any things what is wrong?